# hadoop copy a local file to Hadoop SF error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, file-copying

i want to copy a local file in Hadoop FS. i run this command:

```
sara@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/bin$  hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/sara/Downloads/CA-GrQc.txt /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/${HADOOP_HOME}/hdfs/namenode
```

and

```
sara@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/bin$  hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/sara/Downloads/CA-GrQc.txt /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/${HADOOP_HOME}/hdfs/namenode
```

and even if i run : `hdfs dfs -ls`

i get this error:

```
> WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for
> your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> copyFromLocal: `.': No such file or directory
```

i don't know why i get this error? Any idea please?

Comment: 1) Try to execute `hadoop version` command... Post the output. 2) Fix the output from `hdfs dfs -ls` command, since the output you provided in your question has nothing to do with `-ls` command...

Comment: @Serhiy and for `hdfs dfs -ls`:                                                          
 `sara@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/bin$ hdfs dfs -ls
17/01/26 15:59:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `.': No such file or directory`

Comment: Execute `hadoop fs -ls /` and check if there are not errors.

Comment: @Serhiy when i run `hadoop version` i get :                                             `sara@ubuntu:~$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.3.0
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1567123
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-02-11T13:40Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum dfe46336fbc6a044bc124392ec06b85
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar `

Comment: @Serhiy i get the same error when runing `hadoop fs -ls /`

Comment: 1) OK, if you are on the machine where the namenode is installed, try to access: `127.0.0.1:50070/explorer.html#/` . This will show you the directories you have in HDFS in Web view. 2) Try to execute the following command: `hadoop fs -mkdir test`

Comment: @Serhiy there is no directory in this page. here is the code that i have in **core-site.xml**:<configuration>
<property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
     <description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose
         scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementati
         on.The uri's scheme determines the config property  
         (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming the FileSystem implementation class
         </description>
   </property> </configuration>

Comment: What about the command to create the directory? `hadoop fs -mkdir test`

Comment: @Serhiy i tried this: `hadoop fs -mkdir sampleDir
17/01/26 16:23:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
mkdir: `sampleDir': No such file or directory` when i re-run the same command i get that the **File exists**

Comment: @Serhiy and i run **   hadoop fs -ls /** i get                               `17/01/26 16:28:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - sara supergroup          0 2017-01-26 16:26 /user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your input your Hadoop installation seems to be working fine. What is wrong, it that `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal` expect the directory HDFS directory as target directory, but not the local directory where the Hadoop stores its blocks.

So in you case the command should look like(for example):

```
sara@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.3.0/bin$  hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/sara/Downloads/CA-GrQc.txt /sampleDir/
```

Where the `sampleDir` is the directory you create with `hadoop fs -mkdir` command.

Comment: Exact it's works. i also run : `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/sara/Downloads/CA-GrQc.txt /in` this way the file will be accessible for all users. thanks you for your help.